# Main differences between the 1st and 2nd editions of Unknown Armies

Tags: unknown-armies

I have the 2nd edition of the core rulebook for Unknown Armies, and copies of most of the accompanying splat books, most of which were written before the 2nd edition was published.

I have noticed a number of more subtle differences between the editions that don't make a huge difference, for example changes in terminology, but wanted to know if there is a definitive list of the changes that were made when they moved from the first to the second edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing some rooting around, I have managed to find out most if not all of this myself. The main differences between the two editions are as follows:

- The biggest difference by far is that the 2nd edition is organised into three distinct sections according to the power level you wish to play at. Character creation has also been tweaked so that starting characters also scale according to the power level
- Significantly extended background setting information, with plot hooks liberally scattered through the whole book
- Additional character creation steps/options including the addition of Trigger Events and Paradigm Skills
- General rules were tweaked, including rewriting the initiative system, adding 'fuzzy logic' skill checks, additional combat modifiers and martial arts rules, and a new experience system
- Thaumaturgy was added, as well as new rituals and artifacts
- Proxy magic and tilts were updated
- Five more schools of magic
- Six more avatars
- Additional resources for GMs to assist with the design and running of campaigns

In addition to the main points above, there are numerous smaller changes, for example the removal of the terms BOHICA and OACOWA, which were replaced with Fumbles and Crits respectively.